# Changing the edge color of zoom-rect in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, pyqt4

I have written an app for spectral analysis using python+matplotlib+pyqt.  The plots need to have a black background with white axes and symbols in the app.  I kept the default Navigation toolbar of matplotlib.  One problem I have due to the inverted color setup is that the edge of zoom rectangle is invisible because it is black.  Is there a simple way to change the edgecolor of the zoom rectangle to a bright color, such as white.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Can you add some of the code you are using, so we see exactly what you've done?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Gloweye's response, in PyQt5 you should.

```
import six

import ctypes
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)

QT_API = 'PyQt5'
DEBUG = False

_decref = ctypes.pythonapi.Py_DecRef
_decref.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
_decref.restype = None

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self,self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


    #Change de color of rectangle zoom toolbar rewriting painEvent
    #the original code is in the backend_qt5agg.py file inside
    #matplotlib/backends directory
    def paintEvent(self, e):
        """
        Copy the image from the Agg canvas to the qt.drawable.
        In Qt, all drawing should be done inside of here when a widget is
        shown onscreen.
        """
        # if the canvas does not have a renderer, then give up and wait for
        # FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self) to be called
        if not hasattr(self, 'renderer'):
            return

        if DEBUG:
            print('FigureCanvasQtAgg.paintEvent: ', self,
                  self.get_width_height())

        if len(self.blitbox) == 0:
            # matplotlib is in rgba byte order.  QImage wants to put the bytes
            # into argb format and is in a 4 byte unsigned int.  Little endian
            # system is LSB first and expects the bytes in reverse order
            # (bgra).
            if QtCore.QSysInfo.ByteOrder == QtCore.QSysInfo.LittleEndian:
                stringBuffer = self.renderer._renderer.tostring_bgra()
            else:
                stringBuffer = self.renderer._renderer.tostring_argb()

            refcnt = sys.getrefcount(stringBuffer)

            # convert the Agg rendered image -> qImage
            qImage = QtGui.QImage(stringBuffer, self.renderer.width,
                                  self.renderer.height,
                                  QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
            if hasattr(qImage, 'setDevicePixelRatio'):
                # Not available on Qt4 or some older Qt5.
                qImage.setDevicePixelRatio(self._dpi_ratio)
            # get the rectangle for the image
            rect = qImage.rect()
            p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            # reset the image area of the canvas to be the back-ground color
            p.eraseRect(rect)
            # draw the rendered image on to the canvas
            p.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0), QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImage))

            # draw the zoom rectangle to the QPainter
            ########################################################
            #        HERE CHANGE THE COLOR, IN THIS EXAMPLE        #
            #         THE COLOR IS WHITE                           #
            ########################################################
            if self._drawRect is not None:
                pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white, 1 / self._dpi_ratio,
                                 QtCore.Qt.DotLine)
                p.setPen(pen)
                x, y, w, h = self._drawRect
                p.drawRect(x, y, w, h)
            p.end()

            # This works around a bug in PySide 1.1.2 on Python 3.x,
            # where the reference count of stringBuffer is incremented
            # but never decremented by QImage.
            # TODO: revert PR #1323 once the issue is fixed in PySide.
            del qImage
            if refcnt != sys.getrefcount(stringBuffer):
                _decref(stringBuffer)
        else:
            p = QtGui.QPainter(self)

            while len(self.blitbox):
                bbox = self.blitbox.pop()
                l, b, r, t = bbox.extents
                w = int(r) - int(l)
                h = int(t) - int(b)
                t = int(b) + h
                reg = self.copy_from_bbox(bbox)
                stringBuffer = reg.to_string_argb()
                qImage = QtGui.QImage(stringBuffer, w, h,
                                      QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
                if hasattr(qImage, 'setDevicePixelRatio'):
                    # Not available on Qt4 or some older Qt5.
                    qImage.setDevicePixelRatio(self._dpi_ratio)
                # Adjust the stringBuffer reference count to work
                # around a memory leak bug in QImage() under PySide on
                # Python 3.x
                if QT_API == 'PySide' and six.PY3:
                    ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(stringBuffer)).value = 1

                origin = QtCore.QPoint(l, self.renderer.height - t)
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImage)
                p.drawPixmap(origin / self._dpi_ratio, pixmap)

            # draw the zoom rectangle to the QPainter
            if self._drawRect is not None:
                pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1 / self._dpi_ratio,
                                 QtCore.Qt.DotLine)
                p.setPen(pen)
                x, y, w, h = self._drawRect
                p.drawRect(x, y, w, h)

            p.end()
```

**FOR MATPLOTLIB 2.2.2**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

# HERE CHANGE THE COLOR OF ZOOM RECTANGLE
    def drawRectangle(self, rect):
    # Draw the zoom rectangle to the QPainter.  _draw_rect_callback needs
    # to be called at the end of paintEvent.
        if rect is not None:
            def _draw_rect_callback(painter):
                # IN THIS EXAMPLE CHANGE BLACK FOR WHITE
                pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white, 1 / self._dpi_ratio,
                             QtCore.Qt.DotLine)
                painter.setPen(pen)
                painter.drawRect(*(pt / self._dpi_ratio for pt in rect))
        else:
            def _draw_rect_callback(painter):
                return
        self._draw_rect_callback = _draw_rect_callback
        self.update()

class MplWidget (QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()
        # add the toolbar
        self.ntb = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.vbl = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.ntb)
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
```

Answer (score 1):

in the file

## backend_qt4agg.py

```
# draw the zoom rectangle to the QPainter
#changed code below...
# change the color of zooming rectangle from black to red 
if self.drawRect:
    p.setPen( QtGui.QPen( QtCore.Qt.red, 1, QtCore.Qt.DotLine ) )
    p.drawRect( self.rect[0], self.rect[1], self.rect[2], self.rect[3] )
p.end()
```

just add/change the rectangle drawing portion to the above code.

Comment: it will change it to red color.. you can use your own color

Comment: Great.  Thank you so much.  This answers many of my questions how matplotlib plots are combined with Qt.  However, I wonder if the same can be done without changing the backend_qt4agg.py directly.  It seems that object p is not accessible from outside...

Comment: Not sure about that. I use this changed backend_qt4agg.py for the same reason

Comment: in pyqt5 the file is: backend_qt5agg.py,

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by subclassing and overriding (NOT extending) the paintevent: (Code is copy pasted from the original paintevent, changing the color to a variable)

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg 
import PyQt4.QtCore as QCore
import PyQt4.QtGui as QGui
class FigureCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    """
    Subclassing to change the paint event hosted in matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg. 
    Removed all comments for sake of brevity. 
    Paintcolor can be set by settings canvas.rectanglecolor to a QColor.
    """
    def paintEvent(self, e):
        paintcolor = QCore.Qt.black if not hasattr(self, "rectanglecolor") else self.rectanglecolor
        if not hasattr(self, 'renderer'):
            return
        if self.blitbox is None:
            if QCore.QSysInfo.ByteOrder == QCore.QSysInfo.LittleEndian:
                stringBuffer = self.renderer._renderer.tostring_bgra()
            else:
                stringBuffer = self.renderer._renderer.tostring_argb()
            refcnt = sys.getrefcount(stringBuffer)
            qImage = QGui.QImage(stringBuffer, self.renderer.width,
                                  self.renderer.height,
                                  QGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
            rect = qImage.rect()
            p = QGui.QPainter(self)
            p.eraseRect(rect)
            p.drawPixmap(QCore.QPoint(0, 0), QGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImage))
            if self._drawRect is not None:
                p.setPen(QGui.QPen(paintcolor, 1, QCore.Qt.DotLine))
                x, y, w, h = self._drawRect
                p.drawRect(x, y, w, h)
            p.end()
            del qImage
            if refcnt != sys.getrefcount(stringBuffer):
                _decref(stringBuffer)
        else:
            bbox = self.blitbox
            l, b, r, t = bbox.extents
            w = int(r) - int(l)
            h = int(t) - int(b)
            t = int(b) + h
            reg = self.copy_from_bbox(bbox)
            stringBuffer = reg.to_string_argb()
            qImage = QGui.QImage(stringBuffer, w, h,
                                  QGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
            if QT_API == 'PySide' and six.PY3:
                ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(stringBuffer)).value = 1
            pixmap = QGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qImage)
            p = QGui.QPainter(self)
            p.drawPixmap(QCore.QPoint(l, self.renderer.height-t), pixmap)
            if self._drawRect is not None:
                p.setPen(QGui.QPen(paintcolor, 1, QCore.Qt.DotLine))
                x, y, w, h = self._drawRect
                p.drawRect(x, y, w, h)
            p.end()
            self.blitbox = None
```

Depending on your application, you may be able to shorten in a bit more (like killing the PySide specific part in there). Above works, and you can just use the FigureCanvas as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the necromancy, but I wanted to throw my hat in the ring for anyone who's trying to solve this problem in tkinter (since most answers here deal with Qt).

You'll need to override the `NavigationToolbar2Tk.draw_rubberband()` method. Here I'm using a custom class, but it's not the only way:

```
class CustomToolbar(mptk.NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    def __init__(self, figcanvas, parent):
        super().__init__(figcanvas, parent)  # init the base class as usual

    # you can copy the method 'draw_rubberband()' right from
    # NavigationToolbar2Tk - we're only changing one line
    def draw_rubberband(self, event, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        self.remove_rubberband()
        height = self.canvas.figure.bbox.height
        y0 = height - y0
        y1 = height - y1
        # this is the line we want to change
        self.lastrect = self.canvas._tkcanvas.create_rectangle(
            x0, y0, x1, y1
            outline = 'red'  # add your outline color here
        )
        # hex color strings -> '#FF3344' and named colors -> 'gainsboro' both work
```

You can use the `CustomToolbar` class by name just like you would use `NavigationToolbar2Tk`

```
self.toolbar = CustomToolbar(self.root, self.canvas, self.frame)  # for example...
```

Implementing a custom toolbar class that inherits from `NavigationToolbar2Tk` opens up other possibilities as well, such as modifying toolbar buttons, adding custom tools, and so on...but that's a story for another post.